# ggplot label color based on condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to change the color geom_label_repel based on a condition. For example:

```
res <- data.frame(group = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 5"),
                 correlation = c(0.37,0.33,0.31,0.30,0.30))
res <- res %>%
  arrange(desc(correlation))

res

  group correlation
1 Group 1        0.37
2 Group 2        0.33
3 Group 3        0.31
4 Group 4        0.30
5 Group 5        0.30
```

I want to label the three groups with the highest correlation value. Then I want to change the color of the point with the highest correlation value if the difference between the subsequent group is > 0.03. My code right now gives  me this plot

```
p <- res %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(group, -correlation), y = correlation)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(data = slice_max(res, n = 3, correlation),
                   aes(label = group))
```

[image]

Now, I want to change the color of the Group 1 label because its correlation value is > 0.03 than Group 2's correlation. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't Group 1's correlation 0.04 greater than Group 2's, and 0.04 < 0.3?

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo that's been fixed. The correlation should be > 0.03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this by adding a helper column based on the condition:

```
library(tidyverse); library(ggrepel)
res <- res %>%
  arrange(desc(correlation)) %>%
  mutate(my_col = if_else(
    row_number() == 1 & correlation > lead(correlation) + 0.03,
    "highlight",
    "other"
  )) 


res %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = correlation, color = my_col)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(data = slice_max(res, n = 3, correlation),
                   aes(label = group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("highlight" = "red", "other" = "black")) +
  guides(color = "none")    # optional, hides legend
```

[image]